# Can I expense guest amenities for my AirBnB?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, rental-property, california

I own an AirBnB in California. This is a standalone house, I do not live there.

In the course of operating it we furnish amenities such as Roku devices, or Foosball tables, or BluRay discs.

Can these items be deducted as expenses or otherwise be advantageously considered for tax reasons?

Comment: I think you mean you own a rental in California. You just so happen to use the AirBnB service to find short-term renters. Anything a rental-business would do in regards to taxes applies to you, because you are indeed running a rental-business. Hello Mr. CEO ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. These are expenses related to your trade/business and you can deduct them. You should check under what conditions you can deduct them in full, and if these are not met you may need to depreciate them over their useful life period. Look at [de-minimis safe harbor rule](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/tangible-property-final-regulations) and the [IRC Sec. 179](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/179).

Answer (score 2):

I'd seek the advice of a person that does taxes related to temporary rentals.  While under normal circumstances such items are expense-able, there is a series of litmus tests to see if your property qualifies as a business.  One such test is the number of days rented to friends and family and also used by yourself.

While I am not familiar with the specifics, I am with the generalities due to some woe experienced by a coworker who ran afoul of the IRS rules.